# Differential calculus: word problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The derivation of $$y=xy^2$$ is $$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} =  y^2 + x\cdot 2y \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}.$$
Why we are are putting $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ if we have already derived $y^2$ and its power becomes its coefficient then why $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$?
can any one explain it.

Comment: $y$ is a function of $x$. The derivative of $y^2$ with respect to $y$ is simply $2y$. But the derivative with respect to $x$ requires the chain rule: $${d\over dx} y^2=2y\cdot {d\over dx } y=2y{dy\over dx}.$$

Comment: simplifying $xy^2=y$ implies $xy=1$. Then $y=\frac{1}{x}$ and you don't need the chain's rule to get $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$$

Answer (score 4):

The $\frac{dy}{dx} = y'$ is needed because we are treating $y = f(x)$ as a function of $x$, and by the chain rule $$\frac{d}{dx}\Big(g(y)\Big) = \frac{d}{dx}\Big( g(f(x))\Big) = g'(f(x))f'(x) = g'(y)y' = g'(y)\frac{dy}{dx}$$

So, for example, $$\frac{d}{dx}\Big(y^2\Big) = 2y\cdot \frac d{dx}(y) = 2y\dfrac{dy}{dx}$$

Answer (score 1):

chain rule. if y is a function of x, then differentiating any function of y wrt x would mean first differentiatiing that function wrt to y and then multiplying that by the derivative of y wrt x.

in other words change in x changes that function only through a change in y so you measure how much y changes if x changes and then measure based on that change in y, how much the original function would change. the combination of the two (i.e. product) would be the change in the original change due to change in x